# IndentationError: expected an indented block discord.py

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup, indentation, discord.py

Hello I'm completely new to coding & working on a discord bot with python3 that utilizes bs4 & requests to show me all of the listings on a certain car I'm looking for. Not sure if I'm writing the code right or if the indentation is actually the cause of this problem any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import bs4
import lxml

req = requests.get('https://dallas.craigslist.org/search/cto?query=300zx')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.command()
async def search(ctx):
    listings = soup.findAll('li', class_='result-row')
    listing1 = listings[0]
    def listing():
    global listing1
    for listing1 in listings:
        title = listing1.p.a.text
        link = listing1.p.a['href']
        price = listing1.span.text
    await ctx.send(f'Title: {title}\nLink: {link}\nPrice: {price}')

client.run('token')

  File "bot.py", line 21
    global listing1
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Look at the line prior to line 21

Comment: def listing(): started a nested function definition (on line 20).  Lines belonging to the nested function are not properly indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def listing():
    global listing
    ...
```

You forgot an indentation here